# Create Message box/ pop up message

Tags: vbscript, hta

See these message box images

1: http://catalinx.homeftp.org/img/Autoiterror1.jpg
2: http://www.exceltrick.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Messagebox-Example-5.png

I can create such messagebox using vbs in a notepad as shown in 1st image. But click buttons are like in 2nd image. How to solve it? I'm making an HTA app.

I'm asking how to add particular set of buttons in new style. For example see 2 methods:

```
MsgBox "Hello", 48
```

and

```
Alert "Hello"
```

Both displays same thing with Exclamation. But the style of OK button is different. If we use the 2nd, it is more beautiful than 1st. So i would like to add a cancel buttons to the 2nd method as below

```
Msgbox "Hello",17
```

How?

Comment: `window` has also `confirm()` method, though it shows a questionmark instead of exclamation...

Answer (score 1):

You can't. [`Alert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) takes just a single parameter: the message to display. If you want to control the icon and/or buttons you must use a [`MsgBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28v=vs.84%29) or build your own [custom dialog](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_buttons.php).

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers, I've updated question. I hope you can now understand my topic clearly.

Answer (score 1):

```
X=MsgBox ("hello",48, " ")
```

Description:

```
X=MsgBox ("your message",(button options) ,"title")
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a little old, but I stumbled upon it looking for something else. Since I am here....

I keep this little VBScript handy for any time I use a msgBox and can't think of the responses of the top of my head. You want Yes/No, OK/Cancel, Abort/Retry/Cancel....? Just paste this into a .VBS file with notepad for future reference.

Edit the file to see what button syntax you or looking for, or double-click the VBS to see how each of them work.

Enjoy!

```
Sample = msgBox("Option codes 0+64." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is an information situation with OK only",0+64, "Information.")
    Select Case Sample
        Case 1
            wScript.Echo "You acknowledged."
    End Select

Sample = msgBox("Option codes 1+48." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a warning situation with OK and Cancel",1+48, "WARNING!")
    Select Case Sample
        Case 1
            wScript.Echo "You chose OK."
        Case 2
            wScript.Echo "You chose Cancel."
    End Select

Sample = msgBox("Option codes 2+16." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a critical situation with Abort, Retry, and Ignore",2+16, "CRITICAL!")
    Select Case Sample
        Case 3
            wScript.Echo "You chose Abort."
        Case 4
            wScript.Echo "You chose Retry."
    Case 5
        wScript.Echo "You chose Ignore."
    End Select

Sample = msgBox("Option codes 0+16." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a critical error situation with OK only",0+16, "CRITICAL ERROR!")
    Select Case Sample
        Case 1
            wScript.Echo "You acknowledged."
    End Select

Sample = msgBox("Option codes 3+32." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a question situation with Yes, No, or Cancel",3+32, "Question?")
    Select Case Sample
        Case 6
            wScript.Echo "You said Yes."
        Case 7
            wScript.Echo "You said No."
        Case 2
            wScript.Echo "You clicked Cancel."
    End Select

Sample = msgBox("Option codes 4+32." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a question situation with Yes or No only",4+32, "Question?")
    Select Case Sample
        Case 6
            wScript.Echo "You said Yes."
        Case 7
            wScript.Echo "You said No."
    End Select

Sample = msgBox("Option codes 5+16." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a critical error situation with Retry or Cancel",5+16, "CRITICAL ERROR!")
    Select Case Sample
        Case 4
            wScript.Echo "You clicked Retry."
        Case 2
            wScript.Echo "You clicked Cancel."
    End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

HTA file cab be created by the VBS file and then deleted:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

sHtml = "<div>Value 1 " & _
    "<input id='txt1' style='width: 100px'>" & _
  "</div>" & _
  "<div>Value 2 " & _
    "<select id='txt2' style='width: 100px'>" & _
      "<option value='A'>A</option>" & _
      "<option value='B'>B</option>" & _
      "<option value='C'>D</option>" & _
    "</select>" & _
  "</div>" & _
  "<p align=center>" & _
    "<input type='button' value='Send' onclick='Send()'> " & _
    "<input type='button' value='Close' onclick='self.Close()'>" & _
  "</p>"

  Set oRet = OpenDialog(sHtml, "txt1,txt2", 300, 200, "Dialog 1")
  MsgBox "Value 1: " & oRet("txt1") & ", Value 2: " & oRet("txt2")

'==================================
Function OpenDialog(sHtml, sFields,iWidth,iHeight, sTitle)
  sHtaFilePath = Wscript.ScriptFullName & ".hta"

  CreateHtaFile sHtaFilePath, sHtml, sFields,iWidth,iHeight,sTitle

  Set f = fso.GetFile(sHtaFilePath)
  f.attributes = f.attributes + 2 'Hidden

  Dim oShell: Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  oShell.Run """" & sHtaFilePath & """", 1, True

  If fso.FileExists(sHtaFilePath) Then
    fso.DeleteFile sHtaFilePath
  End If

  Set oRet = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  'Load return data from XML File
  If fso.FileExists(sHtaFilePath & ".xml") Then
      Set oXml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
      oXML.async = False
      oXML.load sHtaFilePath & ".xml"

      For each sField In Split(sFields,",")
        oRet.Add trim(sField), oXML.SelectSingleNode("/root/" & trim(sField)).text
      Next

      fso.DeleteFile sHtaFilePath & ".xml"
  End If

  Set OpenDialog = oRet
End Function

Sub CreateHtaFile(sHtaFilePath, sHtml, sFields, iWidth, iHeight, sTitle)
  Set f = fso.CreateTextFile(sHtaFilePath, True)
  f.WriteLine "<html><title>FL Reporting</title><head><HTA:APPLICATION ID=oHTA SINGLEINSTANCE=""yes"" SCROLL=""no""/></head>"
  f.WriteLine "<script language=""vbscript"">"
  f.WriteLine "Window.ResizeTo " & iWidth & ", " & iHeight
  f.WriteLine "Set fso = CreateObject(""Scripting.FileSystemObject"")"
  f.WriteLine ""
  f.WriteLine "Sub Send()"
  f.WriteLine " Dim sFilePath: sFilePath = Replace(location.href,""file:///"","""")"
  f.WriteLine " sFilePath = Replace(sFilePath,""/"",""\"")"
  f.WriteLine " sFilePath = Replace(sFilePath,""%20"","" "")"
  f.WriteLine " Set oXml = CreateObject(""Microsoft.XMLDOM"")"
  f.WriteLine " Set oRoot = oXml.createElement(""root"")"
  f.WriteLine " oXml.appendChild oRoot"

  For each sField In Split(sFields,",")
    f.WriteLine " AddXmlVal oXml, oRoot, """ & sField & """, GetVal(" & sField & ")"
  Next

  f.WriteLine " oXml.Save sFilePath & "".xml"""
  f.WriteLine " self.Close()"
  f.WriteLine "End Sub"
  f.WriteLine ""
  f.WriteLine "Sub AddXmlVal(oXml, oRoot, sName, sVal)"
  f.WriteLine " Set oNode = oXml.createElement(sName)"
  f.WriteLine " oNode.Text = sVal"
  f.WriteLine " oRoot.appendChild oNode"
  f.WriteLine "End Sub"
  f.WriteLine ""
  f.WriteLine "Function GetVal(o)"
  f.WriteLine " GetVal = o.value"
  f.WriteLine " If o.Type = ""checkbox"" Then"
  f.WriteLine "   If o.checked = False Then"
  f.WriteLine "     GetVal = """""
  f.WriteLine "   End If"
  f.WriteLine " End If"
  f.WriteLine "End Function"  
  f.WriteLine "</script>"
  f.WriteLine "<body>"
  f.WriteLine sHtml
  f.WriteLine "</body></html>"
  f.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

this is ripped straight from vbsedit.com:

```
intButton = object.Popup(strText,[nSecondsToWait],[strTitle],[nType])
```

Comment: where `object` is: `CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`