# Counting number of Lines

Tags: vbscript

I am using below VBScript to count the number of lines

```
Set t1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set t2 = t1.OpenTextFile ("c:\Users\sample.txt", 1)
Do Until t2.AtEndOfStream
    strlinenumber = t2.Line
    strLine = t2.Readline
Loop
MsgBox strlinenumber
t2.Close
```

How to get a customized text in the message box (say "Number of Lines: 22")

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804267/create-message-box-pop-up-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatente the line count with your message text:

```
Do Until t2.AtEndOfStream
    t2.ReadLine
Loop
MsgBox "Number of lines: " & t2.Line
```

You don't need a counter variable, BTW. The `Line` property has the number of lines after you read all lines in your loop.

Comment: Save on the unnecessary loop - Ref [Answer to Function to count number of lines in a text file](//stackoverflow.com/a/14994750)